# @angular-material-components/datetime-picker does not work with string format date

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I just have installed: "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^5.0.3",

I imported:

```js
    import { NgxMatDatetimePickerModule, NgxMatNativeDateModule, NgxMatTimepickerModule } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
```

HTML:

```html
    <ngx-mat-timepicker [(ngModel)]="dateString" showSeconds="true" name="dateString"></ngx-mat-timepicker>
```

Component:

```js
    dateString = new Date().toString(); // this is example value comes from server in string format
```

I am getting error:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: date.getHours is not a function
    TypeError: date.getHours is not a function
        at NgxMatNativeDateAdapter.getHour (angular-material-components-datetime-picker.js:6409)
        at NgxMatTimepickerComponent._updateHourMinuteSecond (angular-material-components-datetime-picker.js:3870)
        at NgxMatTimepickerComponent.writeValue (angular-material-components-datetime-picker.js:3808)
        at forms.js:2389
    ...
```

How to set up time picker to work with string date ? Original material date component works fine with string format, and this component works fine if I use date format, but I need this to work with string format ?

Comment: I think you need to use a date; not a string.

Comment: This component is kind of extension of material date picker, and material date picker works with string and date. Most of date components work with both formats. Strange that this component is not so flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on their source code, they expect a `Date` type only, and they explicitly used the `NgxMatDateAdapter<Date>` to parse/format the Date objects in the `NgxMatNativeDateAdapter`.

For example, you can check the `getHour` function which expects the `Date` as the argument type here: [NgxMatNativeDateAdapter:284](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/blob/master/projects/datetime-picker/src/lib/core/native-date-adapter.ts#L284)

In your case, you can do the following to handle it, based on the [DateAdapter](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/tree/master/projects/datetime-picker#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) you want to use:

- **NgxMatNativeDateAdapter**: Wrap the value always using `new Date(value)` to handle both `string` & `Date` values.
- **NgxMatMomentAdapter**: Wrap the value always using `moment(value)` to handle both `string` & `Date` values.